# ComboBox в гриде

Tags: extjs, javascript

Сделал табличку, данные подгружаются, но все никак не могу понять, как вставить комбобокс в одну из колонок, в моем коде это последняя:

Кто поможет, награжу хорошим кол-вом очков своей репутации :)

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
  Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
      {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
      {name: 'day', type: 'string'},
      {name: 'time', type: 'string'},
      {name: 'what', type: 'string'},
      {name: 'combo', type: 'string'}
    ]
  });

  var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: 't.php',
      reader: {
        type: 'json'
      }
    }
  });

  var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    columns: [
      {
        text: "День", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'day', sortable: true
      },
      {
        text: "Трапеза", width: 115, dataIndex: 'time', sortable: true
      },
      {
        text: "sourse", width: 100, dataIndex: 'what', sortable: true
      },
      {
        text: "Combo тут! как его сделать???", width: 100, dataIndex: '', sortable: true
      }
    ],
    height:700,

    renderTo: 'grid-example'
  });

  store.load();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто становится, когда посмотрите на [документацию](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing).
Надо в `GridPanel` добавить плагин, который будет позволять редактирование.

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        pluginId: 'myId'
    })
 ]
```

Дальше вам необходимо определить ячейки для редактирования:

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'combobox',
    /* все настройки для комбобокса. 
       Но это уже на ваше исследование потому что вопрос
       на другую тему.  
     */
 }
```

Если следовать примеру:

```
columns: [
    {
        text: "Трапеза",
        /* ... ... ...*/
        editor: {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            /* все настройки для комбобокса. 
               Но это уже на ваше исследование потому что вопрос
               на другую тему.  
              */
         }
    }
]
```

Более подробно про комбобокс [тут](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox).
Большой совет научиться пользоваться именно этим ресурсом. 95% информации я черпаю именно от туда.
**PS**
Очки можете приберечь. Мне они ни к чему:)

Comment: Добрый день. Может кто подскажет как сделать чтобы после загрузки таблицы, или выбора значения в комбобоксе, в колонке отображалось значение displayField а не valueField?